# What's the reference for the line in the talmud that is about a Jewish apostate being put into a pit?

Tags: sources-mekorot, talmud-gemara

What's the reference for the line in the talmud that is about a Jewish apostate being put into a pit?

I know that it gets brought down later in the RAMBAM and Shulchan Aruch.

[How are we supposed to understand Rambam's Rotzeach uShmirat Nefesh 4:10?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/112250/how-are-we-supposed-to-understand-rambams-rotzeach-ushmirat-nefesh-410/)

Comment: avodah zara 26b but also, besides the rambam reference mentioned in the q hilchot rotzeach 4:10. , this rambam reference is related hilchot mamrim 3 https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/84160/how-to-understand-hilchot-mamrim-3

Answer (score 2):

You might be thinking of [Avoda Zara 26b](https://www.sefaria.org/Avodah_Zarah.26b.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

> אבל המינין והמסורות והמומרים היו מורידין ולא מעלין
>
> But the heretics, and the informers, and the apostates
> [vehameshummadim] are lowered into a pit, but not raised out of it.

For the Rambam see [MT Rotzeach uShmirat Nefesh 4:10](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1088920/jewish/Rotzeach-uShmirat-Nefesh-Chapter-Four.htm), and for Shulchan Aruch see [CM 425:5](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Choshen_Mishpat.425.5?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en).

Comment: Hilarious that they uncensored it only in English :)

Comment: Yes this is interesting. I checked the paper version of the Steinsaltz gemara and it has the uncensored text on both the Aramaic and English side

Comment: looking at the  aramaic, המינין(heretic),  והמסורות(informer-מוֹסֵר).  mumar(similar to meshumad, some kind of apostate).. (And the aramaic has meshumad plural replaced with/censored to, mumar plural).  This link here mentions a little about mumar and meshumad https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/114182/what-are-the-rabbinic-hebrew-words-that-could-equate-to-anti-torah